# slice string into two variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have coordinates in my attribute data-coordinates

```
<a class="cor" href="#" data-coordinates="37.650621, 55.740887"></a>
```

I need slice them into two variables, like this

```
<script>

//this must contain coordinate which is before ","
var firstCor = $('.cor').attr('data-coordinates');

//this must contain coordinate which is after ","
var lastCor = $('.cor').attr('data-coordinates');


</script>
```

So then, I must have two variable from one data-coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var cor = $('.cor').data('coordinates').split(','); // creates an array of result
var firstCor = cor[0].trim(); // access 1st value index starts from 0
var lastCor = cor[1].trim(); //.trim() to remove empty spaces from start and end
```

[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

[.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

---

Update

For old browser Support use

[$.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) instead of [.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

```
var firstCor = $.trim(cor[0]);
var lastCor = $.trim(cor[1]);
```

or Use [String.prototype.trim polyfill](https://gist.github.com/eliperelman/1035982)

Comment: leaves a space on the second value

Comment: @epascarello used `.trim()`

Comment: FYI if you need to support IE8 with this answer you need to use the polyfill for trim

Answer (score 1):

Use [**.split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), if you want to convert in float use `parseFloat`

```
 var arr = $('.cor').data('coordinates').split(',');
 var firstCor = $.trim(arr[0]);
 var lastCor  = $.trim(arr[1]);
```

Comment: leaves a space on the second value

Comment: @epascarello, Updated answer used `$.trim()`. As `.trim()` is not supported in older browser

Answer (score 1):

```
var co = $('.cor').data('coordinates');

var temp=new Array();

temp=co.split(",");

var firstCor =temp[0];

var lastCor = temp[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a regular expression

```
var cords = $('.cor').data('coordinates').match(/-?\d+\.\d+/g);
```

which results in array with two strings

```
["37.650621", "55.740887"]
```

If you want to convert them to numbers and the browser supports Array map()

```
var cords = $('.cor')
                .data('coordinates')
                .match(/-?\d+\.\d+/g)
                .map( function(a){ return parseFloat(a); });
```

which results in

```
[37.650621, 55.740887]
```